# Formatting Hard disk in C++ on Linux

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to make a program to format Hard Disk and now I'm stuck with the code of the 
formatting  I searched and I found `SHFormatDrive()` but I found that function is supported for win xp and later and I couldn't find away to use it any help!

Comment: 1) What is the problem you're having? *Be specific.* 2) Why do you want to format a hard drive? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am curious.. why do you want to do such a thing ?

Comment: I need to do this code for my friend He asked me to do it pragmatically He is a linux guy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The typical way you do things like this in UNIX is to use the library call system(const char*) to call a command-line utility to do it for you.

Of course, you need proper permissions, etc.

The other way, of course, is to find the open-source formatting code (e.g. mkfs.ext3) and add it to your project (following the licensing requirements, of course).

Answer (score 4):

If you're just looking to destroy the file system on the hard drive (un-format it), you could simply open the hard drive device file for writing, and start writing zeroes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char buf[8192];
    FILE *f = fopen("/dev/sda", "w");
    if(f == NULL) {
       perror("Could not open file for writing");
       return;
    }

    long unsigned int written = 0;

    while(true) {
        unsigned count = fwrite(buf, sizeof(buf), 1, f);
        written += count;
        if(count != sizeof(buf) {
            perror("Could not write file");
            break;
        }; 
    }

    fclose(f);

    printf("Bytes written: %lu\n", written);
}
```

**Note: only use this code in an unmodified version if you really know what you're doing, as this will proably render your root file system/computer unusable!**

If you want to actually format it with a file system such as ext4 or btrfs, you'd have to take a look at those filesystem-specific libraries. You'd best start with reading the source code of the mkfs.btrfs or mkfs.ext4 utilities, but the task is certainly non-trivial.